# Match string but return whole import statement with regex

Tags: regex, replace, import, sass, gulp

I'm setting up a gulp task, which will basically replace any import statement, where it references a file with a development extension.

Example:

```
_main.scss:
     @import '/app/a';
     @import '/app/b.development';
```

So if I run the task, I wanted to have a regex to pull out the second imort statement depending on the mode I run it in.

Gulp replace `https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace` to do this, so I'd have a task setup like so:

```
gulp.task('sass:app', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.src.sass + '**/*.scss')
    .pipe(
        gulpif(
            config.production,
            replace(regexheretomatchfile, '')
        )
    )
)};
```

So my expected output would be:

```
_main.scss:
     @import '/app/a';
```

Excluding the dev import.

My question is, what regex can I use to match the whole regex statement? I'm hopeless with regex.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a site like http://regexr.com/ to test my regular expressions with my 'real-world' data.

The following regex may not be perfect, but should be a good starting point for accomplishing your goal:

```
/@import '.*development';/gi
```

Basically, you're looking for an exact match on the import statement, then 0 or more of *any* character, then the 'development' extension, followed by the ending portion of your line.

The above makes **a lot** of assumptions, not limited to:
- the spacing of your import statements (i.e., how much whitespace there is on each line)
- your consistent use of single-quotes

As I said, I'd use this as a starting point and then tweak to your particular situation.  You'd don't need to go whole hog with a super-complicated regex right at the start.